# Best way to pair a Pre-made Class and primitive type C#

Tags: c#, class, struct, monogame

Basically, I'm wanting to efficiently pair multiple bool and bytes ( to store values ) with a pre-made class (RenderTarget2D if you must know).

Obviously, I can wrap this all in a class, however there are situations when I will be having many of these, and would like to save on memory where possible (ie use a struct).

I know it's bad behaviour to use a struct with reference variables, and I'd prefer not to just use separate variables to hold the information ( would rather pair it all together ).

Essentially I am wanting a structure to hold a reference to a class, a bool, and a byte, and create a 2D array of this to make many (thus am looking for a mitigate memory usage)

Am I overlooking an obvious solution?

Comment: So you want an object that holds a `bool`, a `byte` and an instance of the class `RenderTarget2D`, right? How is it that a `Tuple<bool, byte, RenderTarget2d>` doesn't help you with this?

Comment: "I know it's bad behaviour to use a struct with reference variables" - not particularly, so long as you're aware of the consequences (particularly if the reference type is mutable).

Comment: As Jon Skeet pointed out there are plenty of samples in .Net Framework itself where immutable structs are passed by reference - see any `TryParse` methods for example. But you really should measure first if class or struct is better for your case - pain dealing with structs may be more than performance benefit it could bring. So in current form I feel question is mostly opinion-based...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding the question as:

You want something that holds a `bool`, a `byte` and an instance of the class `RenderTarget2D`.

If that is the case you can use `Tuple<bool, byte, RenderTarget2d>`.

Creating a custom class or struct is also a viable option. In fact there is a proposal for "C# 7" to include language native [tuples](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/347) (that will not be System.Tuple) and as currently written, they will be structs.

---

You may also want to consider that having a reference to the `RenderTarget2d` may prolong its lifespan.

---

**Struct vs Class**

The struct takes in memory (when compacted) the size of a `bool` plus the size of a `byte` plus the size of a reference (to `RenderTarget2d`). If you have an array of 600 by 600 (360000) of such structs it takes 360000 the size of the struct in memory.

If you use classes, the array will have 360000 references to the actual location of the data that in total takes at least as much as the array of structs.

So using the structs should take less memory...

**But** when you take a struct from your data structure, you are actually making a copy. So each time you access your array to get a item and read a property of that item, you are actually making a copy of the item and reading the property from that copy.

If you want to update it, you need to read it (that makes a copy as mentioned above) edit it, and then put it back... and that copies the data to the array.

So, if the memory is the main concern. Use struct. To quote Jon Skeet: "so long as you're aware of the consequences".

---

Using struct also means less RAM round trips. Not only because it avoids resolving the references, but also because the data is guaranteed to be close together. This allows for better performance because the CPU will load a chunk (or the totality) of the data structure in cache and since the code is not using references outside of that it will be able to keep it in cache instead of going to load another thing.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was asking (sorry, my question was laid out poorly).

But would Tuple not bring extra memory consumption for something so trivial? (Since it is a class wrapper) agaisnt say using a struct?

Comment: @user1965626 yes and no. I mean, sure there is an overhead for having a class, but the struct gets copied each time you pass it around. Would need to know more of your use case to decide is a struct is worth while, yet I would expect the overhead of a class to be negligible.

Comment: To avoid too much information, I will have a 2D arrray of this struct/class, which will approx be 600*600 at largest, even so, this isnt too big in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Also, it all mainly be stored locally in a class, it won't be passed around much.

Comment: Thanks very much, I decided on using a class and your input was very valuable

Comment: @user1965626 good to know - sounds like you are using the data enough for the copies to be a problem. Sadly you have objects there, if it weren't because of RenderTarget2D using an array of structs and accessing via pointer arithmetics is much better in terms of performance.